# Django search capabilities

Tags: python, django

Is there a easy way to add a search capability on fields in Django? Also please let me know what is [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Try [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). It's pretty easy to setup.
2. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) is full-text search engine written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) as mentioned above together with [Xapian](http://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack).

Xapian doesn't require you to run it as a process (which is some sort of advantage in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

I second the Haystack suggestion. Here's a [good blog post about it](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2009/nov/2/large-problems-django-mostly-solved/). In fact, the entire series—Large Problems in Django, Mostly Solved—is excellent reading. Here's a [Google search that should find most of the entries](http://www.google.com/search?q=Large+Problems+in+Django%2C+Mostly+Solved+site%3Aericholscher.com&aq=f&oq=&aqi=).

Answer (score 1):

If your database is MySQL don't underestimate the power of QuerySet's [search](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search) method. It uses MySQL's full-text index (assuming you've created one) to do full-text searching. It's the quickest to set up of all the options (it's built in!) and depending on your requirements it may be enough. If not, I also think Haystack is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Haystack setup on my blog application took me <30 min as Django newbie. I can strongly recommend it.