# Whats the easy way to build search engine for website in python

Tags: python, linux, full-text-search

I have one website in django , with many content pages. I want to build the search engine so that if i search for keywords then i get the URL of that Page.

It can be any library or scripts. My Main rquirements is that i should be able to tweak the script or add my own code so that in future i can build the index according my needs.

I also need to build the index fo words with frequency , counts etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django search capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859866/django-search-capabilities)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297672/full-text-search-engine-for-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure python search library would be whoosh:

- http://whoosh.ca/
- http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/add-full-text-search-to-your-django-project-with-whoosh.html